# What was the radiation dose of the witnesses of the Chicago Pile 1 experiment?

Tags: radioactivity

In descriptions of the Chicago Pile 1 experiment, where a self-sustaining chain reaction was first produced, scientists are standing directly around the pile. Some of them are even taking measurements of the radiation within the same room as where the chain reaction is happening.

Wikipedia states that the reactor was operating at about 0.5W of power.

How does this translate to a radiation dose of the spectators? Would this be dangerously high? I would expect that collecting this much Uranium in one place would already cause significant elevations in radiation levels, let alone a chain reaction.

Comment: Well, 1 rad is the absorption of 0.01 J/kg. You can estimate from there...

Comment: Re, "...collecting this much Uranium in one place..." Uranium is just _barely_ radioactive. It's practically harmless \*IF\* you can keep it outside of your body. The risk from handling it or, from breathing the air in a room where somebody else was handling it would be calculated in terms of [_body burden_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomonitoring) rather than radiation dose.

Comment: Small hand-held chunks of Uraninite (Uranium ore) can easily emit >100μSv/hr at the sample's surface. Not enough to be dangerous at a distance, but it does elevate levels.

Comment: @MarkvanderWilk, 100μSv/hr of _what?_ How much of that dose is due to alpha particles? Alphas cannot penetrate human skin deeply enough to affect living tissue. OTOH, I am aware that some of the daughter isotopes will emit betas, and all of the above will emit some gamma radiation, but I confess, I don't actually know the spectrum of energies of the various radiation types.

Comment: These are measurements of 100µSv/hr with Geiger counters that are not sensitive to alpha radiation. I have seen chunks like this in geology exhibitions. I would not put a radiation source emitting 100µSv/hr of beta/gamma in my pocket, even if it is outside of my body. But, I also confess, that it has been hard to find a comprehensive discussion of these kinds of questions!